# How to Add multiple key to a session variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm trying to store Shopping cart data into session variable in laravel,
till now this is how i was doing in my php project

```
if (isset($_SESSION["cart_products"])) {  //if session var already exist
        if (isset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$item_id])) { //check item exist in products array
            unset($_SESSION["cart_products"][$item_id]); //unset old array item
        }
    }
```

After this I was adding that item data into session again to avoid duplicate like shown below

```
$_SESSION["cart_products"][$item_id] = array("Item_name" => $title,
"Price" => $price, 
"Item_id" => $item_id, 
"User_id" => $user); //update or create product session with new item
```

Now how i can achieve the above same method in laravel

This is how i'm trying

```
if (Session::has('cart_products')) {  //if session var already exist
     if (Session::has("cart_products".$item_id)) { //check item exist in products array
     Session::forget('cart_products'.$item_id); //unset old array item
     }
}
```

This is how my Session array Looks

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Item_name] => Mailwizz Frontend theme [Price] => 100 [Item_id] => 1 [User_id] => 1 [image] => images/items/1/1XKSzuh8vkIrsJVdfRZMeF3UH4cimToC75pW0NEa62LgOjw_9yYltQGbnDPqxAB.png [folder] => item1 [Slug] => mailwizz-frontend-theme [Category] => php-scripts ) [1] => Array ( [Item_name] => Mailwizz Frontend theme [Price] => 100 [Item_id] => 1 [User_id] => 1 [image] => images/items/1/1XKSzuh8vkIrsJVdfRZMeF3UH4cimToC75pW0NEa62LgOjw_9yYltQGbnDPqxAB.png [folder] => item1 [Slug] => mailwizz-frontend-theme [Category] => php-scripts ) ) )
```

Comment: any error came?

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR no errors but item id is not being added into it

Comment: How do i check if key exist in multi dimension aray? for e.g `if (Session::has('cart_products')('1')){ echo 'item 1 exist'; } else { echo 'item do not exist'; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your session array & check if the key (ie item_id) already exists or not

Answer (score -1):

Ok, the tricky solution, use `json_encode` method to encode data and then store into session array like.

```
session([
    'cart_products' => json_encode([
        [
          'key' => 'value',
        ]
    ])
]);
```

This may help you!